# Did an impact crater cause the formation of the gas fields in north eastern South Australia

Tags: geology, earth-history

In the paper [High Impact Reservoirs](https://www.slb.com/~/media/Files/resources/oilfield_review/ors09/win09/02_high_impact_reservoirs.pdf), the authors claim that impact craters have lead to both the creation and destruction of petroleum source rocks, reservoirs and traps.

Recently it was [announced](http://www.sbs.com.au/news/article/2013/02/15/worlds-third-largest-asteroid-impact-zone-found-sa) that a large impact crater may have been discovered in the East Warburton region of South Australia. The announcement was base on [new research](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040195113000188). If this is true, and allied with the finding presented in the paper on High Impact Reservoirs, could the recently announced impact crater in South Australia have lead to the formation of the [Moomba gas fields](http://www.pir.sa.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0014/111056/203838_004.pdf) in the Cooper and Eromanga basins which are within the East Warburton Basin region?

[image]

Comment: I believe there are two impact craters Glikson has discovered in that region of Australia. See [this](http://googleearthcommunity.proboards.com/thread/1019/consolidated-impact-crater-database-ekafeman) comprehensive database of structures.